# How can I implement ICEFaces2 into a JSF2 project in metbeans 7?

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

First, I'm blind and the section of ICEFaces Wiki give me some problems when I try to read it.
Second, I'm also Italian so sorry for my poor and, perhaps, bad english.
Ok, now I'll try to explain my issue.
I have a project that works properly and that implement JSF2.0, now I would add the support to ICEFaces because I would use the autocomplete combo box and some other components.
The first thing that I did was install the plug-in on netbeans7, the second was modifiy the properties of my project adding the framework ICEFaces, now I would try it,because I had some problems in the past and I wrote also this question:

[ICE Faces and error in creation of a bean in WindowScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001426/ice-faces-and-error-in-creation-of-a-bean-in-windowscoped)

after that I change many things so I had discard the ICEFaces implementation but now I would add this framework.
The problem is that the project doesn't work anymore and, as I wrote, I just add the support to the framework!
An example of my page that doesn't work:

```
<h:form> <h:commandLink action="/progetti/List.xhtml" value="Elenco dei Progetti"/> </h:form>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone tell me where I did the error?

[EDIT:] as I said I tried it some times ago so I don't remember what I did the last time so I reload the icefaces web site and I found this page:

http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v2_devguide/html/Adding%20ICEfaces%20to%20Your%20Application.html

And I check my web.xml and It is ok the only thing that I changed is this code:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

with this code:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/icefaces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

obviously it doesn't resolve my issue...

Comment: I feel sorry that I can't help you (I do not use ICEfaces nor Netbeans). But I'd be interested if there is any particular reason that you're specifically looking at ICEfaces? There are other component libraries which also have an autocomplete component like [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces) and [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org). Or is the problem that you cannot find/read their documentation using the screen reader tools for the blind?

Comment: @ BalusC : well the last time I choosed ICEFaces because it was the only that had the window scoped and support mojarra... now Ichange the logic on my project and I can ignore the window scoped so I could change... ok I will try to open the web site of these  frameworks and if its seems without any issue I will change framework!

Comment: All JSF component libraries support Mojarra. Even more, it does not matter which JSF implementation you're using. As to the documentation, RichFaces has an extensive [Developer Guide as HTML](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/). PrimeFaces has as an [Users Guide as PDF](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_1.pdf). I'm however not sure if you can read PDF files easily. I have used them both and particularly PrimeFaces is really easy to install. Just one JAR file without any necessary additional XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolve my problem... how? I don't know...
The project is under SVN so, after the question, I revert my project so I could continue to work ok? Well, now the project support ICEFaces and works quite properly!
So the first problem is into ICEFaces plug-in and the implementation of ICEFace from Add framework on netbeans. Now the project doesn't link directly the libraries of ICEFaces but link, probably, these into Glassfish server!
If someone will have this problem, my suggestion is: add the libraries into server and try to add some ice components and, perhaps, it will work!